Make protoc available for Bazel build
Ideally, this is not a Rust-specific question, but just for background: I am working on a Rust project that uses tonic for gRPC access, but expands its functionality a bit, so it uses a custom build.rs script to invoke the proto definition compiler protoc. I have a Bazel project (using MODULE.bazel instead of WORKSPACE) that defines a cargo_build_script section in my BUILD.bazel file to run build.rs, and as long as I run it on a system that already has protoc available, everything builds perfectly. If I uninstall protoc, it starts failing with
Error: Custom { kind: NotFound, error: "Could not find `protoc`. If `protoc` is installed, try setting the `PROTOC` environment variable to the path of the `protoc` binary. To install it on Debian, run `apt-get install protobuf-compiler`. It is also available at https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases  For more information: https://docs.rs/prost-build/#sourcing-protoc" }

I need Bazel to also run the build script inside our CI pipeline, which doesn't come with protoc by default, so I am trying to find the simplest possible way to just make protoc available to Bazel. I found toolchains_proto, but I haven't been able to get it to work yet. I'm still pretty new to Bazel. So, apologies if this is a trivial question.
It looks like most of the tool-chains (including the one linked above?) are intended to do the protobuf compilation in a separate build step rather than as part of Rust's build.rs. If possible, I would like to avoid this and instead just find a way to have Bazel grab the protoc binary and make it available in such a way that I can add it to the deps in my cargo_build_script rule (if "rule" is the right word), allowing me to still call it myself as I please with custom args and such.

To make protoc available in your Bazel-based build without requiring a manual installation, you can use Bazel's http_archive to download and unpack the protoc binary directly in your workspace, then make it available in your cargo_build_script rule.
Here's a general approach you can try:

Download protoc binary via http_archive:
In your WORKSPACE file, you can define an http_archive rule to download the precompiled protoc binary for your platform.
http_archive(
    name = "protoc",
    urls = ["https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/releases/download/v24.1/protoc-24.1-linux-x86_64.zip"],  # Make sure to adjust for your platform
    strip_prefix = "protoc-24.1",
)

Adjust the urls field according to the version of protoc you want and your platform (e.g., Linux, macOS, Windows).

Expose protoc as a toolchain or an executable:
After downloading it, you can expose it as an executable target so your build.rs can call it. In your BUILD file, create a rule to expose the protoc binary.
filegroup(
    name = "protoc_bin",
    srcs = ["@protoc//:bin/protoc"],
)


Make protoc available in your cargo_build_script rule:
Now, modify your cargo_build_script rule to reference this protoc binary and set the PROTOC environment variable.
cargo_build_script(
    name = "my_build_script",
    srcs = ["build.rs"],
    data = [":protoc_bin"],  # Make protoc binary available
    env = {
        "PROTOC": "$(location :protoc_bin)",
    },
)

This will ensure that the build.rs script can use the protoc binary downloaded by Bazel during the build process.

Ensure correct platform handling:
If your CI pipeline runs on multiple platforms, you’ll want to adjust the http_archive to download the correct binary for each platform. You can do this by using platform-specific logic in your WORKSPACE file to download the appropriate protoc binary.


By using this approach, Bazel will handle fetching the protoc binary, and your CI pipeline won’t depend on having it pre-installed.

Unfortunately this doesn't work. We're using a MODULE.bazel based repo rather than WORKSPACE, but if I add http_archive there, it says name 'http_archive' is not defined.
I did some Googlin' and it said I could use:
http_archive = use_repo_rule("@bazel_tools//tools/build_defs/repo:http.bzl", "http_file")
to make it available, but when I add that, it now complains that strip_prefix isn't defined in http_file and also env isn't defined in cargo_build_script.

If I remove both of those, I get
no such package '@@_main~_repo_rules~protoc//': BUILD file not found in directory '' of external repository @@_main~_repo_rules~protoc. Add a BUILD file to a directory to mark it as a package. And at this point, I'm not sure what to try next...
